# Show that, $-\gamma=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln\Gamma(1+x)}{x}$

Tags: limits

**Definition**

Where $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ and $\gamma=0.577216...$ is a Euler's constant

Show that,

$$-\gamma=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln\Gamma(1+x)}{x}$$

Comment: Isnt the quotient positive ?

Comment: You shouldn't use $n$ for the variable in the limit, this is misleading.

Comment: Is $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$ really your definition of $\Gamma$? Do you know how $\Gamma$ is defined?

Comment: Is this not the wolfram definition of defining this function?

Comment: @ Najib please help edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [Weierstrass product for the $\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Alternative_definitions)
$$\Gamma(t+1)=e^{-\gamma t}\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^{-1}e^{\frac{t}{n}}\tag{1}$$
and by considering $\frac{d}{dt}\log(\cdot)$ of both sides we have:
$$ \frac{\Gamma'(t+1)}{\Gamma(t+1)}=-\gamma+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{t}{n(n+t)}\tag{2}$$
so by letting $t\to 0$ it follows that:
$$ \frac{\Gamma'(1)}{\Gamma(1)} = \color{red}{-\gamma}.\tag{3}$$
By De l'Hopital theorem,
$$ \lim_{n\to 0}\frac{\log\Gamma(n+1)}{n} = \frac{\Gamma'(1)}{\Gamma(1)}.\tag{4}$$